# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES ()

Tags: datatable

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1 migrated from Magento 1.9.4 using the Migration tool
Smartwave Porto theme which came with Mageplaza Layered Navigation and Search
10 Extensions from Amasty
```

We used the Magento Migration tool to migrate data and settings from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.2-p1. The primary store (Main website) loads, works and accepts orders as expected. It is the 2nd website and the 3rd one as well that is giving me the following Error when trying to check-out with the Cash or Check Payment option:

```
A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.
```

I have changed the following in:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php
```

Changed this:

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    $email,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $email, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

**to this:**

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    $email,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $email, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __($e->getMessage()),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

Which produced a **more specific Error**:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES ()
```

In this article here:

[magento 2 Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES ()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110701/magento-2-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1103-incorrect-table-name-query)

It explains that **...the above error occurs when there is missing tables for multi-stores. The main reason behind the issue is when the migration is done using any third party extension not done by Data migration tool.*

**I have**, however, **used the Data Migration Tool.**

*It further says:

*this issues you got when you try insert new row to a table relation ship to sequence auto generate . to resolve this issues , please see in table "sales_sequence_meta" with "entity_type" = "order" , check and make sure this entity_type = "order" exist on all your stores . Insert new one if you check it missed for any store id.*

**I don't know how to insert new rows into a table. Would someone please post step by step instructions on how to do that via phpMyAdmin?**

Also, is this something that could have been caused by either extensions from Amasty or the Mageplaza Layered Navigation and Search extensions or the Smartwave Theme? If that was the case, I could ask their support to fix this.

I found the following in the database (in phpMyAdmin):

```
mget_sequence_creditmemo_0
mget_sequence_creditmemo_1
mget_sequence_creditmemo_6
mget_sequence_creditmemo_7

mget_sequence_invoice_0
mget_sequence_invoice_1
mget_sequence_invoice_6
mget_sequence_invoice_7

mget_sequence_order_0
mget_sequence_order_1
mget_sequence_order_6
mget_sequence_order_7

mget_sequence_shipment_0
mget_sequence_shipment_1
mget_sequence_shipment_6
mget_sequence_shipment_7
```

**Does that mean that these tables are missing in the database for stores 2, 3, 4 and 5? And how do you tell which store is which number?** Is 0 Default Config and 1 the Main Website, then 2 the next website and so on? It is possible I created website 6 and 7 by hand after the migration. Is that the reason why these tables are there for 6 and 7?

---

UPDATED on October 26th, 2021:

I have followed STEP1 in the below proposed solution and added:

```
sequence_order_2
sequence_order_3
sequence_order_4
sequence_order_5
```

As can be seen here:

[image]

**Do I also need to add the following for 2, 3, 4 and 5?**

```
mget_sequence_invoice
mget_sequence_creditmemo
mget_sequence_shipment
```

**I am really confused about STEP 2! Looking at the screenshot I posted right above - what do I need to add for:**

```
1] profile_id
2] meta_id column
3] prefix column
4] other columns
```

---

UPDATED again on October 26th, 2021:

I have done step 1 successfully I believe:

[image]

Can I just confirm that my STEP 2 given the information above for STORE 2 would be this?

```
 INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '23', 'mget_', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

**Is** `1] profile_id: auto-incremented value` **the store number such as 2 for my first additional store and 8 for your example?**

Looking at my screenshot below - I believe I figured out most of the values:

```
**`profile_id` --> is this 2 for store 2?
`meta_id` --> is this 2 for store 2?**
`prefix` = NULL
`suffix` = NULL
`start_value` = 1
`step` = 1
`max_value` = 4294966295
`warning_value` = 4294966295
`is_active` = 1
```

---

I found the following:

```
mget_sales_sequence_profile
```

[image]

---

**After looking at the information in my database (please see screenshots above) I now believe the script should be this:**

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      2, '2', 'NULL', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

**I tried to run it but get the following Error:**

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      2, '2', 'NULL', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   )
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

---

UPDATED on October 31st, 2021:

I'm following the steps and when I get to:

2] You need to add meta_id column value from step 1 query to step 2 below query respected store id's 2/3/4/5.

For this template:

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'Your Step four Query Meta Id Value of invoice', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   )
```

My specific SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '2', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '3', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '4', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '5', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

---

Updated on October 31st, 2021 again:

*I believe I have gone through all of the SQL* recommended by Jitendra Patel
but **when I try to place a test order now on the 2nd website/store - I get the following Error:**

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'denverga_mage341.mget_sequence_order_2' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mget_sequence_order_2` () VALUES ()
```

**What did I do wrong and how to correct it? Here are a couple of screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

I also ran the following after adding the SQL in phpMyAdmin:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

### **but it didn't help.**

---

Updated again on October 31st:

I have gone through ALL of the SQLs again, some of them inserted and others gave the Duplicate Error but I am still getting this Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'denverga_mage341.mget_sequence_order_2' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mget_sequence_order_2` () VALUES ()
```

**I must be doing something wrong? Am I possibly putting this in the wrong place in the database?**

More screenshots of the current status quo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also *restarted HTTP Server (Apache), PHP-FPM service for Apache, SQL Server (MySQL) as well as the whole server altogether.*

*I ran the following:*

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**But I'm still getting the same Error.**

I tried this again and phpMyAdmin says it already exists?

[image]

---

UPDATED on November 1st, 2021:

I am honestly not sure what *mget_sequence_order_2 table missing in your database for store id 2* means but more importantly, **how do I fix it?** I really have gone through all the SQL twice and it didn't make the mget_sequence_order_2 table in my database for store id 2?

The Admin panel shows the following:

[image]

I was also able to confirm store ID 2 exists by going to:

Content > Design > Configuration -> Select the Store for which require the store ID and click “Edit” -> The store ID is displayed in the URL as can be seen below:

[image]

---

---

Here is a **SUMMARY** of the problem:

- I migrated from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.2-p1 using the Magento Migration Tool. It appears that during the Migration, some tables were not created and now my Main Website works fine but the 2 additional stores give an Error message when submitting the order such as:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'denverga_mage341.mget_sequence_order_2' doesn't exist, query was:
> INSERT INTO `mget_sequence_order_2` () VALUES () REREWREWR

@Jitendra Patel was kind to give me some SQL to insert into the database via phpMyAdmin (thank you Jitendra). I have gone through all of these several times = it now just gives me the Duplicate (can't create this because it already exists) Error but somehow the table is not getting created? or Magento is not seeing it? This can be seen I think in this screenshot here:

[image]

It is entirely possible I am doing something wrong as I have never inserted tables into a database before. The way I do it is:

```
- find the Table in the line under Tables
- go to SQL
- put the SQL code there and click on Go
```

**Has anybody got any suggestions on what I can try?** I'm really desperate to get this working. Thank you.

---

---

---

Here is the **SOLUTION** which **fixed this problem for me**:

```
CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_creditmemo_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_invoice_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_order_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_shipment_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_creditmemo_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_invoice_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_order_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_shipment_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_creditmemo_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_invoice_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_order_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_shipment_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I found that in *this post here*:

[magento 2 Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES ()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110701/magento-2-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1103-incorrect-table-name-query)

The answer presented by Jitendra Mandloi.

I have only done the first part (see above). Would anyone know if I also need to do the other steps in Jitendra Mandloi's post or have I done that already by doing the steps outlined by Jitendra Patel in his answer below? **Everything appears to be working right now.**

The other steps suggested by Jitendra Mandloi are as follows (the ones I haven't done):

---

Following tables need to be updated with the corresponding sequence profile table entries:

sales_sequence_meta sales_sequence_profile

Note: Need to change store id in below queries.

```
INSERT INTO `sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) VALUES
(NULL, 'order', 3, 'sequence_order_3'),
(NULL, 'invoice', 3, 'sequence_invoice_3'),
(NULL, 'creditmemo', 3, 'sequence_creditmemo_3'),
(NULL, 'shipment', 3, 'sequence_shipment_3');
```

**Note**: Change prefix as store id for below query.

```
INSERT INTO `sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) VALUES
(NULL, 17, 3, NULL, 1, 1, 4294967295, 4294966295, 1),
(NULL, 18, 3, NULL, 1, 1, 4294967295, 4294966295, 1),
(NULL, 19, 3, NULL, 1, 1, 4294967295, 4294966295, 1),
(NULL, 20, 3, NULL, 1, 1, 4294967295, 4294966295, 1);
```

Comment: First thing your database table start with the "mget_" prefix so you need to add that. as I see in your updated screenshot it's showing without table prefix "mget_" from meta_id 17 to 20.

Comment: I have updated answer with prefix table name and also added queries for invoice and shipment sequence.

Comment: @Jitendra Patel I think I am almost done just a bit uncertain about step 2. Would you please look at my update? Thank you for helping!

Comment: @Jitendra Patel I've done the 1st step correctly I think but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in Step 2 (I'm getting an Error message). Would you please re-write your code for step 2 and 3 using the information from my screenshots? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jitendra Patel Thank you for all your help so far. I think I've gone through all the SQLs you suggested but I get the following Error when trying to submit an order on website/store 2: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'denverga_mage341.mget_sequence_order_2' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO mget_sequence_order_2 () VALUES () Would you please look at my last update in my original post? Thank you.

Comment: @Jitendra Patel I have gone through all the SQLs again but I am still getting the Error (please see the update in my original post). Am I doing something wrong still or do I need to reindex the database somehow for this to take effect? Thank you Jitendra.

Comment: @Jitendra Patel I have really botched this up and now I'm having problems updating orders because of that. Would you please look at my new post (reference below) and see if you can help? Thank you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/349820/unique-constraint-violation-found-when-updating-existing-orders

Answer (score 1):

The first fall same thing happens in my project after Data migration.

I have fixed the issue with the following steps.

Step 1: Find out the missing store id order sequence. in my case store id 8.

So I have executed the below insert query in the sales_sequence_meta table for store id.

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'order', '8', 'mget_sequence_order_8'
   );
```

Find the below screenshot for your reference after adding above query for store id 8.

[image]

Step 2 : Execute below insert query in sales_sequence_profile
table for same store id

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '41', '78', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

Please note the below points.

```
1] profile_id: auto-incremented value

2] meta_id column: 41 value for meta id based on step first query
auto-increment value.

3] prefix column: in my case is present otherwise set as NULL

4] other columns you can check already present records in your
table.
```

Find the below screenshot for your reference after adding step 2 query.

[image]

Step 3 : Add invoice sequence entry for invoice are as below.

```
   INSERT INTO
       `sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'invoice', '2', 'mget_sequence_invoice_2'
       );



    INSERT INTO
   `sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'your_invoice_meta_id_of_first_query', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

Step 3 : Add shipment sequence entry for shipment are as below.

```
INSERT INTO
       `sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'shipment', '2', 'mget_sequence_shipment_2'
       );

       INSERT INTO
   `sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'your_shipment_meta_id_of_first_query', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   )
```

Please note that above is example query just use your generated automatic meta id in second query from first query and replace your store id from above queries.

Revised update answer for specific for your case.

A] FOR ORDER : As per your screenshot find the following  entries for sales sequence profile table for diffrent store id's order of sales sequence meta.

```
1] You have already done as per your screenshot.

2] I have already added meta_id column values based on your screenshot in below queries.
EX : 23/24/25/26 for store id's 2/3/4/5
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '23', '2', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '24', '3', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
 INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '25', '3', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );     
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '26', '4', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

B] For INVOICE : You have to follow below 2 steps for invoice of store id's 2/3/4/5.

```
1] INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'invoice', '2', 'mget_sequence_invoice_2'
       );
INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'invoice', '3', 'mget_sequence_invoice_3'
       );
INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'invoice', '4', 'mget_sequence_invoice_4'
       );
INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'invoice', '5', 'mget_sequence_invoice_5'
       );
```

2] You need to add meta_id column value from step 1 query to step 2 below query respected store id's 2/3/4/5 and meta id's is 27,28,29,30

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '27', '2', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '28', '3', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '29', '4', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, '30', '5', NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

C] For SHIPMENT : You have to follow below 2 steps for shipment of store id's 2/3/4/5

```
1] INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'shipment', '2', 'mget_sequence_invoice_2'
       );
INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'shipment', '3', 'mget_sequence_invoice_3'
       );
INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'shipment', '4', 'mget_sequence_invoice_4'
       );
INSERT INTO
       `mget_sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) 
    VALUES
       (
          NULL, 'shipment', '5', 'mget_sequence_invoice_5'
       );
```

2] You need to add meta_id column value from step 1 query to step 2 below query respected for store id's 2/3/4/5.

```
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'Your Step First Query Meta Id Value of shipment', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'Your Step second Query Meta Id Value of shipment', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'Your Step third Query Meta Id Value of shipment', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
INSERT INTO
   `mget_sales_sequence_profile` (`profile_id`, `meta_id`, `prefix`, `suffix`, `start_value`, `step`, `max_value`, `warning_value`, `is_active`) 
VALUES
   (
      NULL, 'Your Step four Query Meta Id Value of shipment', NULL, NULL, '1', '1', '4294967295', '4294966295', '1'
   );
```

---

Comment: I tried to go through the steps you suggested and updated my original post. If you would please take a look at my UPDATE in my original post? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Actually in my case we only handle up to order place so I did not require for invoice and shipment. But if you generate invoice and shipment then you may require that.

Comment: I think I am almost done just a bit uncertain about step 2. Would you please look at my update? Thank you for helping!

Comment: I've done the 1st step correctly I think but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in Step 2 (I'm getting an Error message). Would you please re-write your code for step 2 and 3 using the information from my screenshots? Thank you so much!

Comment: I have updated my answer for your specific case. please check now.

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far. I think I've gone through all the SQLs you suggested but I get the following Error when trying to submit an order on website/store 2: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'denverga_mage341.mget_sequence_order_2' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mget_sequence_order_2` () VALUES ()  Would you please look at my last update in my original post? Thank you.

Comment: Hey, Based on the updated screenshot I have added meta id and prefix columns value for order and invoice for step 2 queries. please check & make that correction in mget_sequence_profile_table.

Comment: I have gone through all the SQLs again but I am still getting the Error (please see the update in my original post). Am I doing something wrong still or do I need to reindex the database somehow for this to take effect? Thank you Jitendra.

Comment: Hey, mget_sequence_order_2 table missing in your database for store id 2. Also first cross-verify all the stores in store list in the admin panel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am honestly not sure why I'm missing the mget_sequence_order_2 table in my database for store id 2? How can I fix it? I really have gone through all the SQL twice. Why didn't it make the mget_sequence_order_2 table for store id 2? I've uploaded a screenshot of STORES from Admin into my original post.

Comment: I was also able to confirm store ID 2 exists by going to: Content > Design > Configuration -> Select the Store for which require the store ID and click “Edit” -> The store ID (2) is displayed in the URL as can be seen in the screenshot I uploaded.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I was able to resolve the problem by following steps in the post I mentioned at the end of my original post. You definitely deserve the 50 bounty points for trying to help. Would you mind reading my last update in the my original post and let me know if I'm good now or if I need to do any more in your opinion? Thanks!

Comment: I have verified your updated post and saw that you have created a table manually which was not created by Magento Automatically only this point was pending. now you have completed all the steps.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Jitendra. I have awarded you the 50 bounty points. All the best!

Comment: Thank you!!!  happy to help the community :)

Comment: I have really botched this up and now I'm having problems updating orders because of that. Would you please look at my new post (reference below) and see if you can help? Thank you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/349820/unique-constraint-violation-found-when-updating-existing-orders

Answer (score 0):

**The solution which worked for me was the combination of the steps provided by Jitendra Patel and this**:

```
CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_creditmemo_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_invoice_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_order_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mget_sequence_shipment_2` (
  `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_creditmemo_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_invoice_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_order_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_shipment_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`);

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_creditmemo_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_invoice_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_order_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `mget_sequence_shipment_2`
  MODIFY `sequence_value` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```