# How to share customer data between 2 websites in the same Magento install?

Tags: customer, customer-account

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
extensions from Amasty
```

I've manually duplicated our 2nd website because of problems we were having (as can be seen here: ['Unique constraint violation found' - when updating existing orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/349820/unique-constraint-violation-found-when-updating-existing-orders/349942#349942) )

I have done the following:

- set up a new website, store and store front
- connected the new website to the existing categories (from the old 2nd website)
- I've gone through the products and added them to the new website
- I've added the new website/store/storefront to the appropriate CMS pages and blocks
- I've added extension configuration to include the new website

*Then I've done a test order and:*

- The great news is - I don't have the same problem with updating orders which I had on the old website (as referenced above)
- there are, however, **2 problems**:

  > **1.** The websites do not share the same customer information (login info etc.)

  > **2.** I get the following Error after submitting an Order:

  Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

(the order is submitted but the Error comes up which will annoy customers)

**How to resolve #1 and #2 above?**

---

UPDATED on November 23rd, 2021:

What I want to do is the following:

I have these websites in the same Magento install:

- website 0
- website 1
- website 2
- website 3
- website 4
- website 5

*I want to share customer information only between store 2 and 5.* Would I be able to use this Export/re-import process?

`-> System -> Data Transfer -> Export -> select website 2` in the 'Associated to Website' drop-down here:

[image]

**Then Import this into website 5? Would this work?**

---

**I have tried the Customer Export and re-import as stated above but it does not appear to be working. Would anyone know why that might be? I have documented that in more detail here:**

[I have created an identical website/store (ID in database 8) to another existing website/store (website ID 2) and everything works except logging in](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350109/i-have-created-an-identical-website-store-id-in-database-8-to-another-existing)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have single account for all multi-stores you have to do the following:

**1 Share customer accounts**

You can configure this feature here: System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Share Customer Accounts.

Comment: Thank you for that Gohil. I saw this was an option in the Admin panel. I was hoping to just share 2 websites (not all). If not possible, what would happen to accounts that had the same user name/password on 2 different websites? Does turning this on merge the already created accounts or does that only work going forward? There surely must be a way to only share the customer information between 2 websites in the same Magento install and leave 1 other website out of it?

Comment: it will share only customer.. customer can able to login through same credential on both site.  please check once how its working.

Comment: Thank you trying to help. I decided to go through the route of Exporting customers from website/store 2 and re-import into website/store 8 but it doesn't work (does not log anyone in). Would you happen to know why and how to fix this? More details are here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350109/i-have-created-an-identical-website-store-id-in-database-8-to-another-existing